# Select children of optgroup only on tag click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, optgroup

I am attempting to use an `optgroup` label to select all of the option in the group.

This is working fine, however, when I also select a group `<option>` it selects all `optgroup` elements. How do I make it so selection is based on only the `optgroup`tag?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("optgroup").on("click", function() {
    $(this).children("option").prop("selected", true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <optgroup label="Group1">
    <option value="11">Option 1</option>
    <option value="12">Option 2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Group2">
    <option value="21">Option 1</option>
    <option value="22">Option 2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the tag name of the element since it will bubble.. loop thru each of the options and only check ones that are not checked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("optgroup").on("click", function(e) {
    if(e.target.tagName === 'OPTGROUP'){
      $(this).children("option").each(function(){
        this.selected = !this.selected;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple size=6>
  <optgroup label="Group1">
    <option value="11">Option 1</option>
    <option value="12">Option 2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Group2">
    <option value="21">Option 1</option>
    <option value="22">Option 2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: it does *actually work* based on what you described: `I also need it to deselect the elements if they are already selected.` your edit contradicts that statement.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my earlier statement (it was not derogatory by any means), but yes... Semantics... You did answer my question which is why I accepted the answer... However, realistically toggling selected items (even though I see the wording conflict in my first note) seems counter productive as it appears to respond with semi-unexpected behavior from a visual standpoint... Either way this is a good answer and gives what I needed due to you mentioning the `.tagName` attribute, thanks again!